# How to implement blog log-in?

Tags: authentication, blogs

Hey there, I got a little silly question..

After a healthy dose of some [Atwood's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com) reading, I remembered [Rob Conery's](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) post about [building your own blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/be-a-good-jedi-build-your-own-blog/), so, I thought it would be a nice little pet project to do.

I was thinking a little bit about it, when then I noticed that neither of their blog's have a "log in" button, reasonably enough, since nobody but them are supposed to log in. My little doubt now is, how do they authenticate to the Administrative section?

Would it be through another url something like admin.theblog.com? Or do they use a completely different back end, and then the blog just show the posts?

Just wondering..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you plan to do and who is going to use it.
So yes, it could be another url, a login button in plain sight or even something like login button showup if someone with a static ip adress accesses the page.

So I guess there is no universal answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

I know for Wordpress blogs the admin page is usually the blog URL followed by /wp-admin. No need to put a link on the page, since you generally don't want everyone to see it.

Comment: yeah, thats sort of what I thought, but I just found it a little odd... Thanks!